# DNS redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com

Tags: redirect, web, dns

I have a domain registered with godaddy and I am facing some problem in redirecting www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com

I have tried to redirect it by creating an A host record and CNAME records but it is not working. I am unable to find out the solution to this problem.

Also I have tried doing this by .htaccess file and PHP but still not able to do so.

thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way to do it is with something like mod-rewrite where you just rewrite all URLs to not include the Www. There are tons of tutorials on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@All thanks for the replies.

I just figured it out my self.

It was quet simple. I just deleteed the previous forwarding and re entered the forwarding settings.

also i created a .htaccess file and put a statement in it.
        Redirect http://www.domain.com http://domain.com

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect via DNS records, DNS records can only "resolve" the host.domain to an IP.

To redirect www.domain.com to domain.com use something like this in the website's VirtualHost, or in the .htaccess file (if the .htaccess is enabled for rewriterules)...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all the ServerAliases to domain.com.

mod_rewite needs to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have *domain.com* pointing to to the correct site (ie. when you go to *domain.com* you get to the correct site) then all you need to do is have a 301 Redirect from *www.domain.com* to *domain.com*. It should be found under URL Forwarding on GoDaddy.

Otherwise you would begin by setting a CNAME record on *domain.com* to point to your site and then proceed with the 301 Redirect described above.